# Expected an indented block cant find the problem

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have been working on my own kind of civilisation game and i am working on so you can change the taxes but I get this error for an `elif` about your choices in the tax  changing thing this is the code:

```
moneytalk = int(input("your people doesn't like the new tax do you want to tell them why you have made it so high? 1 = yes, 2 = no"))
if moneytalk == 1:
    talkingmoney = int(input("1 = we have been losing so much money that the goverment needs more, 2 = we have trades that we need to have money for, 3 = its under our avrage right now so we need to higher it"))
    if talkingmoney == 1:
        if my_stats_on_my_city["Gold"] <= 1000:
             print ("your people belive in you and they are no angry with you")
        else:
            moneyrandom = randint(1, 10)
            if moneyrandom >= 6:
                print ("they belive you")
            else:
                print ("they know you are lying and are even more upset now")
                My_people_info["Happines"] -= 5;
                My_people_info["Happines"] -= int(higher);
    elif talkingmoney == 2:
        pass #i will add here after the trading system
    elif talkingmoney == 3:
elif moneytalk == 2:
    My_people_info["Happines"] -= 3;
    My_people_info["Happines"] -= int(higher);
```

And I get the following error:

```
elif moneytalk == 2:
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: I got an `IndentationError` at line 2.

Comment: What are these `;` supposed to mean?

Comment: it's basic rule of python: maintain indentation, use some good editor IDE to avoid such mistake

Answer (score -1):

```
    elif talkingmoney == 2:
        pass #i will add here after the trading system
    elif talkingmoney == 3:
elif moneytalk == 2:
    My_people_info["Happines"] -= 3;
    My_people_info["Happines"] -= int(higher);
```

You don't have any code under the `elif talkingmoney == 3:` branch. There needs to be a `pass` statement at a minimum.

Comment: But the Indentationerror in the question (traceback) seems to be related to the `elif moneytalk == 2:` part (note the `2` not the `3`).

Comment: @MSeifert yes; errors with indentation can't be detected until the parser encounters code that can't possibly have valid indentation. Because there is no user-intended body for the `elif talkingmoney == 3:` block, Python (which *requires* a body for every block) attempts to parse `elif moneytalk == 2:` as the first line of that body; but it is not indented far enough to qualify as such.

Answer (score -1):

```
moneytalk = int(input("your people doesn't like the new tax do you want to tell them why you have made it so high? 1 = yes, 2 = no"))
if moneytalk == 1:
    talkingmoney = int(input("1 = we have been losing so much money that the goverment needs more, 2 = we have trades that we need to have money for, 3 = its under our avrage right now so we need to higher it"))
    if talkingmoney == 1:
        if my_stats_on_my_city["Gold"] <= 1000:
             print ("your people belive in you and they are no angry with you")
        else:
            moneyrandom = randint(1, 10)
            if moneyrandom >= 6:
                print ("they belive you")
            else:
                print ("they know you are lying and are even more upset now")
                My_people_info["Happines"] -= 5;
                My_people_info["Happines"] -= int(higher);
    elif talkingmoney == 2:
        pass #i will add here after the trading system
    elif talkingmoney == 3:
      # You need to paas any statement over here
elif moneytalk == 2:
    My_people_info["Happines"] -= 3;
    My_people_info["Happines"] -= int(higher);
```

You need to paas any statement over here under

> elif talkingmoney == 3: